# Copying Standard Object information and line items to custom object with a trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am creating a custom invoicing tool.  When an Order or Opportunity is closed then an Invoice (invoice__c) is automatically populated with the line items copied to the invoice line items custom object (invoice_line_item__c).

I try and create my triggers using the same flow, I have a generic trigger that calls a triggerhandler class and finally an actions class which is called from the appropriate handler.  I won't copy my trigger and triggerhandler class here as I am certain they are working as expected.

The following code correctly creates the trigger, it is bulkified hopefully too (currently executed from Order or Opportunity After Update context.

```
public static void opportunityCreateInvoice (List<Opportunity> newOpportunity){
    System.debug('Executing opportunityCreateInvoice');
    List<Invoice__c> newInvoices = new List<Invoice__c>(); //list of new invoices to create

    //popupate the set with the opportunity ID's
    for (Opportunity o : (List<Opportunity>) newOpportunity){            
        //create a new Invoice if the criteria is met
        if (o.isWon == True && o.is_locked__c != true) { 
            newInvoices.add(
                new Invoice__c(
                    Created_Date__c = date.today(),
                    Opportunity__c = o.ID,
                    Status__c = 'Draft')
            );
        }
    }
    insert newInvoices;
    // The Invoice Trigger on After Insert inserts the related invoice line items.     
}
```

As you can see from the above I thought it best to create the line items for the invoice once the invoice is created.  Therefore I have an invoice trigger  (and associated code) that runs on afterInsert.  This code should look up the order or opportunity Id from the Invoice that was created and then grab the line items from that record inserting new invoice line items related to the new invoice (I hope that makes sense).

The code is hopefully going to be designed to work with both the Order and Opportunity objects without too much duplication.  I've tried a few things without success (no records are created as I am struggling how to look up the Invoice ID of the new record at the same time as inserting without creating too many for loops...

```
public without sharing class InvoiceActions {

    public static void AutoAddInvoiceLineItems (List<Invoice__c> newInvoice, Map<Id,Invoice__c> newInvoiceMap){
        System.debug('Executing AutoAddInvoiceLineItems');
        List<Invoice_Line_Item__c> newInvoiceLineItems = new List<Invoice_Line_Item__c>(); //list of new product stocks records to reduce the stock holding
        Set<Id> invoiceIdSet= new Set<Id>(); //set of Invoice Id's
        Set<Id> OppyIdSet= new Set<Id>(); //set of Oppy Id's if the invoice is for an opportunity
        Set<Id> OrderIdSet= new Set<Id>(); //set of Order Id's if the invoice is for an order
        Map<Id, Invoice__c> newInvoices = (Map<Id, Invoice__c>) newInvoiceMap; //typed map of new invoice objects

        String OrderOppy;
        Invoice__c ivc = new Invoice__c();
        //popupate the set with the opportunity ID's
        for (Invoice__c o : newInvoice){            
            invoiceIdSet.add(o.Id);
            if (o.Opportunity__c != NULL){
                OppyIdSet.add(o.Opportunity__c);
                OrderOppy = 'Opportunity';
            }
            if (o.Order__c != NULL){
                OrderIdSet.add(o.Order__c);
                OrderOppy = 'Order';

            }
        }   
        system.debug('Order or Oppy = ' + OrderOppy);
        //Get the Line items
        if(OrderOppy == 'Order'){
            List<OrderItem> items = new List<OrderItem>([SELECT Quantity, 
                                                         UnitPrice, Product2.Id, Product2.Name, OrderId, order.status, order.is_locked__c, description 
                                                         FROM OrderItem WHERE OrderId IN :OrderIdSet]);
            for (OrderItem  oi : items){
                newInvoiceLineItems.add(
                    new Invoice_Line_Item__c(
                        product__c = oi.product2.id,
                        quantity__c = oi.quantity,
                        Sale_Price__c = oi.UnitPrice,
                        Description__c = oi.Description
                        //invoice__c = - not sure how to get this.
                    )
                );
            }           
        }

        if(OrderOppy == 'Opportunity'){
            List<OpportunityLineItem> items = new List<OpportunityLineItem>([SELECT Quantity, 
                                                     UnitPrice, Product2.Id, Product2.Name, Opportunity.isWon, Description, Opportunity.isClosed, 
                                                      Opportunity.is_locked__c, Opportunity.Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityID IN :OppyIdSet]);
                //for each and every line item on the opportunity...

         for (OpportunityLineItem  oli : items){
                newInvoiceLineItems.add(
                    new Invoice_Line_Item__c(
                        product__c = oli.product2.id,
                        quantity__c = oli.quantity,
                        Sale_Price__c = oli.UnitPrice,
                        Description__c = oli.Description
                        //invoice__c = - not sure how to get this.
                    )
                );
            }   

        } 

        system.debug(newInvoiceLineItems);
        //insert the records.
        insert newInvoiceLineItems;
    }
}
```

The above obviously produces an error that the invoice line items parent ID is not there.  On reading i definately lack some understanding so will go and read more samples.  I obviously want it bulkified too :(

Still learning this so happy for any recommendations on better code structure, syntax and understanding !!!

Especially as I probably need to duplicate a lot of those to create a proforma object too!  I also want to apologies for asking a "fix this" question but if someone spots a specific concept I have got stuck on - then I am happy to change question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your code over to an `after insert` context, instead of `before insert` or either `update`. Records in a `before` context won't have an id, until the `after insert` stage.

Create maps out of the data you query from your invoices. Then, you can pull a single record or list of records via the related Opportunity or OrderItem.

```
// Uses special sObject map constructor 
Map<Id, OrderItem> orderedItems = new Map<Id, OrderItem>([ ... ]);

// Need special constructor here - cant make this list by hand 
// Opp Id, List of Line Items 
Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItem>> LineItemsByOpp = new Map<Id, List<OpportunityLineItem>>();

List<OpportunityLineItem> LineItems = new List<OpportunityLineItem>([SELECT Quantity, 
                                            UnitPrice, Product2.Id, Product2.Name, Opportunity.isWon, Description, Opportunity.isClosed, 
                                            Opportunity.is_locked__c, Opportunity.Id FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityID IN :OppyIdSet]);
// for all items, check if theyre in the map 
for (OpportunityLineItem item:LineItems) {
    // If theres a key, we add to the existing list 
    if (LineItemsByOpp.containsKey(item.OpportunityId)) {
        // Gets list then adds to list 
        LineItemsByOpp.get(item.OpportunityId).add(item);
    } else {
        // Creates new key, with a new list 
        LineItemsByOpp.put(item.OpportunityId, new List<OpportunityLineItem>{ item }); 
    }
}

// Iterate over our newly created records (With ids)
for (Invoice__c invoice:newRecords) {
    // set the rest of the fields .. 

    if (invoice.Opportunity__c != null) {
        // Since there can be more than one line item, we need to keep all new items in a list 
        List<Invoice_Line_Item__c> invoiceItems = new List<Invoice_Line_Item__c>();

        // loop over all line items under project related to invoice 
        for (OpportunityLineItem lineItem:LineItemsByOpp.get(invoice.Opportunity__c)) {
            Invoice_Line_Item__c item = new Invoice_Line_Item__c();

            // Set the item to relate to the invoice 
            item.Invoice__c = invoice.Id; 

            // set fields via reference to lineItem

            // once done add to list 
            invoiceItems.add(item);
        }

        // we can add all items at once to the list 
        newInvoiceLineItems.addAll(invoiceItems);
    } else if (invoice.Order__c != null) {
        Order__c orderItem = orderedItems.get(invoice.Order__c);

        // Create an item for each record 
        Invoice_Line_Item__c item = new Invoice_Line_Item__c();

        // Set the item to relate to the invoice 
        item.Invoice__c = invoice.Id; 

        // set fields via reference to order__c

        newInvoiceLineItems.add(item);
    } else {
        // throw error, or something - invalid state 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for the comments. I had to make a small adjustment (changed hasKey to containsKey) but has definately pointed me in the right direction.  Now to implement a way to stop triggers firing more than once :D